# Delete from cursor till first character x (spanning multiple lines)

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I know that I can delete from the cursor till and including the first occurence of a character *x* with `dfx`. This only works on one line. How can I delete from the current cursor position till the first occurence of *x* when *x* is not in the same line?

E.g., if the cursor is after the first space in

> yada yada yada
> yada yada yada x

and I type `dfx` the result needs to be:

> yada

Comment: in your example you seem to want to remove until the last occurence of `x`

Comment: @guillem you're right. That was a copy-paste error. Anyhow, I tried to accomplish what I asked on the example with the error, but did not manage to do so. I asked another question: [delete from cursor till nth occurence of character x](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/delete-from-cursor-till-nth-occurence-of-character-x).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `/` for forward search:

```
d/x<CR>
```

and `?` for backward search:

```
d?x<CR>
```

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to comment on romainl's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet!

Although it needs one more keystroke, I find it useful to do `v/x<CR>d` to see the portion that is being removed.

Comment: That's a valid answer.  No need to put it in a comment.  We're only talking about one piece of software (with its variations), so you don't necessarily need to get fancy to have a valid answer-worthy answer.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers you should select this answer if this is what you'll now use.

Comment: @PaulEvans I don't agree. Although this answer has more practical value for me, I think that the accepted answer provides a better answer to the question asked (since it does exactly what is requested -- I did not ask to see the text highlighted first).