# Delete from cursor till nth occurence of character x

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste

I know that I can delete from the cursor till and including the first occurence of a character *x* with [`d/x<CR>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/delete-from-cursor-till-first-character-x-spanning-multiple-lines#5240) or with [`v/x<CR>d`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/delete-from-cursor-till-first-character-x-spanning-multiple-lines#5241) if I want to see the selection first and then delete. How can I delete from the current cursor position till the *n*th occurence of *x*?

E.g., if the cursor is after the first space in

> *yada yada yada
>
>   yada yada yada x
>
>   yada yada yada x
>
>   yada yada yada x*
>   xx

and I type a command to remove up to the third *x* the result needs to be:

> *yada
>
>   xx*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do :

`wd4/x<Enter>`

If you start on the top left of your text

**Explanation**

- `w` : move to beginning of next word
- `d` : delete
- `4/x<Enter>` : until the 4th occurence of x

If you don't know the number of times you would like to do it beforehand, you can also do : `d/x<Enter>` and then hit `.` to repeat

Comment: Bonus tip: This also works with `f` and friends (`F`, `t`, `T`, `;`): e.g. `2fx` will get you to the second `x`, or `2;` will repeat the last `f` twice.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: This only works for letters in the current line.

Answer (score 17):

You can do this by typing

```
<n>df<x>
```

where:

```
<n> is the number of occurrence of particular character
df<x> means delete till you find the occurrence of character x
```

Comment: Note that this solution only works if the <x> character is in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<n>macro
```

is commonly used in vim to repeat the macro "n" times.

so in order to delete till 1st occurrence of x, you would use 
`1dfx`.
Similarly, to delete till the 3rd occurrence of x, you would use `3dfx`.

Comment: I think you missued the word "macro": in vim a macro is a sequence of key recorded in a register and call with `@x` where `x` is your register. What you are referring to is a normal mode command.

Comment: Yes I meant a normal command. But this is true for a macro as well. We can run the macro n times by adding a number before the macro.

Comment: Yes that's true. I was just pointing out that `<n>macro` isn't a standard notation in vim for the macros and as your answer uses a normal mode command it is pretty much the same as kapil's one.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
yada yada yada$
yada yada yada x$
yada yada yada x$
yada yada yada x$
xx$
```

where the `$` indicate ends of lines (`:set list` mode), if the cursor is at the start of second `yada` in the first line, first we have to back up to the preceding space using <kbd>h</kbd>, to include it in the deletion. Then just <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. In other words, just a count in front of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. The result is exactly:

```
yada$
xx$
```